# Input language switching in password fields

Tags: input-language

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 with **Gnome 3.28.2**. Interesting behavior of the input language switcher. When focus is changed to a password field (at least in browser), the language switcher icon in the tray is hidden, and the language is set to a default one. My problem is that the default one is not my system default and is not the one I use for passwords. And I cannot find how I can set the language for password fields.

Is there a way to turn off this function or to manually set the language for the password fields?

Edit: After giving it more thought, it can be related to the fact, that on my system I use Korean layout as default (which includes English), and Russian as the second one. Korean requires ibus to be typed, and probably Gnome does not like such layouts for password. Still the question stays the same.

More details: it is not related to any specific application. Entering password for WIFI produces the same issue.

Edit 2: Did some more testing:

- The input sources setting states:

```
org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources [('ibus', 'hangul'), ('xkb', 'ru')]`
```

- When I add English layout to the input layouts list, when the focus is on the password field I still have the language choosing icon in the tray, allowing me to choose from English and Russian. English is always chosen by default (if it was set on Korean at the moment of focusing on the password field).
- If the password field has "show password" option, when the password is shown I can choose Korean input layout as normal.

So it looks that GNOME does not like to use ibus composition when inputting hidden fields. Which makes sense, but does not make the life easier.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson done

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Added some details

Comment: Do you think that [this bug](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1566357) applies?

Comment: `ibus-hangul` uses the `kr+kr104` keyboard layout, but it's indeed similar to English (US).

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Yes, it is same issue. No solution, though.

Comment: Your observation in the latest edit, i.e. that it's hidden input fields where you can't use IBus input methods, is valuable info. It would be great if you could add a comment to the bug report with that info. +++ So it looks like you run into a bug. Personally I'm not aware of any workaround. Maybe someone else is.

Comment: Thanks for the bug comment!